# How can I pass a navigation parameter value to 2 tabs in Maui?

Tags: maui

New to Maui.

Here is my AppShell code:

```
<ShellItem x:Name="entryForm">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:EntryForm}" Route="EntryForm" />
</ShellItem>

<TabBar>
    <Tab Route="Results">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Tab1"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
            Route="Page1" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="Tab2"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"
            Route="Page2" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

How can I pass the navigation parameter of the entry to both tabs when clicking the relative button in EntryForm?

Comment: `when clicking the relative button in EntryForm`, do you mean there are two buttons that navigates to Page1 or Page2?

Comment: You have a typo: `Rouete="Page1"`

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT No, I mean relative to the action of presenting the tabs. There is a single button. When clicked the two tabs should appear, the 1st one selected, but the parameter should have passed to both of them, so when the 2nd one is selected by the user it would present the right content.

Comment: @StephenQuan I fixed the typo. It wasn't there in my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register ViewModel as Singleton and inject it into any page or ViewModel you like.

Let's say you have following view model to share data:

```csharp
public class SharedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private string _text = string.Empty;

    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In **MauiProgram.cs** register it as Singleton:

```csharp
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SharedViewModel>();
```

After that feel free to inject SharedViewModel into your view models or EntryForm and other tabs and bind Text property in XAML:

```csharp
public partial class EntryPage : ContentPage
{
    // Constructor injection
    public EntryPage(SharedViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: First try of your suggestion and I'm getting the following error `System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for type 'MyApp.EntryPage'.'`

Is the constructor called somewhere without parameters? Where?

Comment: Make sure you registered Pages in **MauiProgram.cs** as well. In my case this is:
`builder.Services.AddTransient<EntryPage>();`